# Keras - TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. OR ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I'm a beginner with python and Keras and I've been trying to train a model for a few days now and I just can't get it to work. I'm trying to learn with code I found online, but applying it to a project I actually have use for.

My data is a 1100 rows (timesteps) by 9 columns (8 input columns and 1 target column). This is formated as a dataframe and all data is numerical.

I've tried everything I could think of to get the .fit to work. It either spits the following error when I df.values and np.reshape() (any shape gives the same error it seems) for the x and y:

```
    train_dfY = train_df.pop("indoorT").values
    train_dfY = np.reshape(train_dfY,[train_dfY.shape[0],1])
    train_df = train_df.values
    train_df = np.reshape(train_df,[train_df.shape[0],train_df.shape[1],1])
    
    history = model.fit(train_df, # input data
                        train_dfY, # target data
                        #batch_size=1, # Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32.
                        epochs=1000, # default=1, Number of epochs to train the model. An epoch is an iteration over the entire x and y data provided
                        #verbose=1, # default='auto', ('auto', 0, 1, or 2). Verbosity mode. 0 = silent, 1 = progress bar, 2 = one line per epoch. 'auto' defaults to 1 for most cases, but 2 when used with ParameterServerStrategy.
                        callbacks=None, # default=None, list of callbacks to apply during training. See tf.keras.callbacks
                        validation_split=0.2, # default=0.0, Fraction of the training data to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. 
                        #validation_data=(X_test, y_test), # default=None, Data on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch. 
                        shuffle=True, # default=True, Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch) or str (for 'batch').
                        class_weight=None, # default=None, Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.
                        sample_weight=None, # default=None, Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for weighting the loss function (during training only).
                        initial_epoch=0, # Integer, default=0, Epoch at which to start training (useful for resuming a previous training run).
                        steps_per_epoch=None, # Integer or None, default=None, Total number of steps (batches of samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined. 
                        validation_steps=None, # Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is a tf.data dataset. Total number of steps (batches of samples) to draw before stopping when performing validation at the end of every epoch.
                        validation_freq=100, # default=1, Only relevant if validation data is provided. If an integer, specifies how many training epochs to run before a new validation run is performed, e.g. validation_freq=2 runs validation every 2 epochs.
                        max_queue_size=10, # default=10, Used for generator or keras.utils.Sequence input only. Maximum size for the generator queue. If unspecified, max_queue_size will default to 10.
                        workers=1, # default=1, Used for generator or keras.utils.Sequence input only. Maximum number of processes to spin up when using process-based threading. If unspecified, workers will default to 1.
                        use_multiprocessing=True, # default=False, Used for generator or keras.utils.Sequence input only. If True, use process-based threading. If unspecified, use_multiprocessing will default to False. 
                       )
```

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

When I don't do that, and just use the dataframe directly in the .fit

```
 train_dfY = train_df.pop("indoorT")
 train_df = train_df
 history = model.fit(train_df, # input data
                        train_dfY, # target data
                        #batch_size=1, # Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32.
                        epochs=1000, # default=1, Number of epochs to train the model. An epoch is an iteration over the entire x and y data provided
                        #verbose=1, # default='auto', ('auto', 0, 1, or 2). Verbosity mode. 0 = silent, 1 = progress bar, 2 = one line per epoch. 'auto' defaults to 1 for most cases, but 2 when used with ParameterServerStrategy.
                        callbacks=None, # default=None, list of callbacks to apply during training. See tf.keras.callbacks
                        validation_split=0.2, # default=0.0, Fraction of the training data to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. 
                        #validation_data=(X_test, y_test), # default=None, Data on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch. 
                        shuffle=True, # default=True, Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch) or str (for 'batch').
                        class_weight=None, # default=None, Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.
                        sample_weight=None, # default=None, Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for weighting the loss function (during training only).
                        initial_epoch=0, # Integer, default=0, Epoch at which to start training (useful for resuming a previous training run).
                        steps_per_epoch=None, # Integer or None, default=None, Total number of steps (batches of samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined. 
                        validation_steps=None, # Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is a tf.data dataset. Total number of steps (batches of samples) to draw before stopping when performing validation at the end of every epoch.
                        validation_freq=100, # default=1, Only relevant if validation data is provided. If an integer, specifies how many training epochs to run before a new validation run is performed, e.g. validation_freq=2 runs validation every 2 epochs.
                        max_queue_size=10, # default=10, Used for generator or keras.utils.Sequence input only. Maximum size for the generator queue. If unspecified, max_queue_size will default to 10.
                        workers=1, # default=1, Used for generator or keras.utils.Sequence input only. Maximum number of processes to spin up when using process-based threading. If unspecified, workers will default to 1.
                        use_multiprocessing=True, # default=False, Used for generator or keras.utils.Sequence input only. If True, use process-based threading. If unspecified, use_multiprocessing will default to False. 
                       )
```

, it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=           time  outdoorT     solar  ...   day_cos  year_sin  year_cos
34350 -1.729690 -1.495782  0.271588  ... -0.155365  1.695961  1.740258
34351 -1.726542 -1.474955  0.438078  ... -0.185550  1.692997  1.737054
34352 -1.723395 -1.454128  0.590666  ... -0.215635  1.690033  1.733849
34353 -1.720247 -1.433301  0.741901  ... -0.245604  1.687069  1.730644
34354 -1.717099 -1.412474  0.902520  ... -0.275443  1.684104  1.727440
        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
35445  1.717099 -0.429443 -0.934947  ...  1.280595 -1.749471 -1.706482
35446  1.720247 -0.433608 -0.934947  ...  1.266811 -1.752798 -1.709570
35447  1.723395 -0.437773 -0.934947  ...  1.252437 -1.756126 -1.712658
35448  1.726542 -0.441939 -0.934947  ...  1.237480 -1.759454 -1.715746
35449  1.729690 -0.443327 -0.934947  ...  1.221947 -1.762783 -1.718834

[1100 rows x 8 columns]
```

Any help as to how to format the x and y for .fit would be greatly appreciated!!! Keep in mind that I am a beginner though :)
Cheers

Comment: What are the shapes for `train_dfY` and `train_df`?

Comment: @AayushPanda `train_df` is (1100, 8) and `train_dfY` is (1100,)